# Error while import tensorflow module

Tags: python, windows, installation, tensorflow, pip

I try to learn TensorFlow with Python. My problem is with import TF module. Here is my configuration: **Python 3.6.1**, **Windows 7** (with MSVCP140.dll)

I've installed TensorFlow by command (in power shell). It works.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

But when I run python environment and try import Tensor Flow

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get errors, this error raise another errors related with it, but at the beginning I want to resolve this first

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Jacek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])   File
>   "C:\Users\Jacek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py",
>   line 296, in find_module
>       raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name) ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is downgrade Python to version 3.5, and install again TensorFlow. It works for me

Comment: May or may not - this is known to be caused by running the wrong version of cuDNN for CUDA when attempting to us GPU.

Comment: I installed 'simple' version of TF without CUDA support

Comment: This is not a solution.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was the cuDNN Library for me - for whatever reason cudnn-8.0-windows10-x64-v6.0 was NOT working - I used cudnn-8.0-windows10-x64-v5.1 - ALL GOOD!

My setup working with Win10 64 and the Nvidia GTX780M:

- Be sure you have the lib MSVCP140.DLL by checking your system/path - if not get it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
- Run the windows installer for python 3.5.3-amd64 from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/) - DO NOT try newer versions as they probably won't work
- Get the cuDNN v5.1 for CUDA 8.0 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) - put it under your users folder or in another known location (you will need this in your path)
- Get CUDA 8.0 x86_64 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
- Set PATH vars as expected to point at the cuDNN libs and python (the python path should be added during the python install)

If you run Windows 32 be sure to get the 32 bit versions of the files mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known error. There is a file named `MSVCP140.DLL`, that you will need in your system to run TensorFlow. Check if this file is in your `%path%`. If it is not, download Visual Studio C++. It is free and you can download it here: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/cplusplus.

Comment: I had this file, and installed update 3 for VS C++ 2015. Do you think about specified location?

Comment: If you had both the DLL and Visual Studio C++ installed, it is probably something failing with your python. Try downgrading python to 3.5.

Comment: anyone know if these instructions need to be updated in 2019?  


about to tackle this.  

I have installed anaconda in ubuntu 18.40 on windows 10 current version. and followed the instructions on tensorflow.org to install tensorflow (CPU) version.
this resulted in python3.7 in addition to th default python 2.7 included in ubuntu.   


trying to get jupyter notebook version running,   
sudo apt install jupyter-core  python3-notebook  jupyter python-ipykernel 
this installed another version of python (3.6)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:-

Don't suffer a lot. Simply downgrade your python version from 3.6.1 to 3.5.2 and

install tensorflow again.. you need not to upgrade the package.

"pip install tensorflow" will automatically download latest version (probably

1.0.1)

Steps:-

Step 1:- conda search python

Step 2:- conda install python=3.5.2

Step 3:- pip install tensorflow

Step 4:- import tensorflow as tf

Horray!!.. It works..

Hope you may not get the same error again!!

Comment: This is a good first step - if you still have issues see answer below - related to cuDNN version.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I used an anaconda environment with Python 3.5 and PIP version 19 but had the same problem. so instead of PIP, I used Conda package manager:

```
conda install TensorFlow
```

it worked well after using Conda instead of PIP

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GPU in your system and it is conflicting with the current set of libraries or throwing a cudnn error then you can add the following line in your code to disable the GPU

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
```

put this in your code and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install tensorflow-gpu`

Install this package this helps me to solve my issues
or else use python 3.9.7

Answer (score -1):

```
    Images=load_images('./datasets/train/images/')
filename = df['filepath'][0]
def getFilename(filename):
    filename_image = xet.parse(filename).getroot().find('filename').text
    filepath_image = os.path.join('./datasets/train/images/',filename_image)
    return filepath_image
getFilename(filename)
image_path = list(df['filepath'].apply(getFilename))
image_path[:10]
bbox_coords = df.iloc[:,1:].values
labels = []


for ind in range(len(image_path)):
    image = image_path[ind]
    img_arr = cv2.imread(image)
    h,w,d = img_arr.shape
    xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax = bbox_coords[ind]
  nxmin,nxmax=int(xmin/(w/255.)),int(xmax/(w/255.))
nymin,nymax=int(ymin/(h/255.)),int(ymax/(h/255.))
    labels.append((nxmin,nxmax,nymin,nymax))

labels = np.array(labels)

X = np.array(images,dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array(labels,dtype=np.float32)

X = X / 255.
y = y / 255.

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train,y_train,test_size=0.1,random_state=42)


model = Sequential()
model.add(VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="sigmoid"))

model.layers[-6].trainable = False

model.summary()


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


r = model.fit(X_train,
              y_train,
              epochs=10,
              batch_size=32,
              validation_data=(X_val,y_val),
              verbose=1)


plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(r.history['loss'],'r',label='train loss')
plt.plot(r.history['val_loss'],'b',label='validation loss')
plt.xlabel('No. of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.title('Loss Graph')
plt.legend()



plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.plot(r.history['accuracy'],'r',label='train accuracy')
plt.plot(r.history['val_accuracy'],'b',label='validation accuracy')
plt.xlabel('No. of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy Graph')
plt.legend()

loss, acc = model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
print("Test Loss:",loss)
print("Test Accuracy:",acc)


model.save('license_plate_detector.h5')
```