# Is it recommended to use TensorFlow under Ubuntu or under Windows?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am a newbie to TensorFlow (and the whole deep learning as well). I have a machine with dual boot, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.
Under which OS should I install and run TensorFlow? Windows or Ubuntu?
Also, what is the recommended Python environment? Anaconda or native pip?

Comment: Read the the documentation... "NOTE: The conda package is community supported, not officially supported. That is, the TensorFlow team neither tests nor maintains this conda package"... Either OS is supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier for you to use Ubuntu if you have the possibility. Getting lapack and blas libraries from sources is easier in linux (you can get precompiled packages for windows though). I prefer native pip, but for windows and for starting Anaconda should be the choice.

Comment: Note that it is easier only on recent Ubuntu LTS versions (16.04 or 14.04) - other versions are not supported by NVIDIA, and are thus harder to get up and running.

I've tried to setup CUDA 8.0 on my 17.04, and it's not very easy (still doesn't work after a few hours of tinkering).

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna work in a flexible and compatible environment, follow these steps:-

1. Install Anaconda in your Windows 10. (free of cost)
2. Install Pycharm Community Edition. (free of cost)
3. Install all the necessary packages needed for your system. (Most probably, 
   scientific processing packages like numpy, scipy, matplotlib, scikit-learn packages are already been installed while installing your above-mentioned platforms.
4. Now follow the link given below..

[How to install tensorflow in Windows Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370953/error-while-import-tensorflow-module/43373862#43373862)

Done!!