# cannot run tensorflow in windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I successfully installed tensorflow on my windows 10 using the cmd command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

However, when I use PyCharm to run a simple code such as:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 node1 = tf.constant(3.0, dtype=tf.float32)
 node2 = tf.constant(4.0) # also tf.float32 implicitly
 print(node1, node2)
```

I get the following error on the console:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\site-
  packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in 
  swig_import_helperfp, pathname, description = 
  imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
  raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
  ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\site-
  packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\site-
  packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
  _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\site-
  packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in 
  swig_import_helper
  import _pywrap_tensorflow
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Desktop/ML/tfbasics.py", line 1, in <module>
  import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\site-
  packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\site-
  packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
  raise ImportError(msg)
  ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\site-
  packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in 
  swig_import_helper
  fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', 
  [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
  raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
  ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\site-
  packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\site-
  packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
   _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\lib\site-
  packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in 
  swig_import_helper
  import _pywrap_tensorflow
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
```

I researched the web to fix this bug but found conflicting results that did not help. Anyone can point to why this bug is occurring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure why you used Mac when you want to run it on Windows

> pip3 install --upgrade
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/**mac/cpu**/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl

from the manual

> Issue the appropriate command to install TensorFlow inside your conda
>   environment. To install the CPU-only version of TensorFlow, enter the
>   following command:
>
> (tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/**windows/cpu**/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
>   To install the GPU version of TensorFlow, enter the following command
>   (on a single line):
>
> (tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/**windows/gpu**/tensorflow_gpu-1.3.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Also please dont forget

> TensorFlow only supports version 3.5.x of Python on Windows. Note that
>   Python 3.5.x comes with the pip3 package manager, which is the program
>   you'll use to install TensorFlow.

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing out my error. Is it ok for python 3.6 ??

Comment: @Dr.YounesHenni wont work with 3.6.x, look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370953/error-while-import-tensorflow-module?noredirect=1&lq=1