# Failed to import tensorflow in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I tried to "import tensorflow".
I encountered the following error.
What's wrong in this case?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from ._api.v2 import compat
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import compat
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import v1
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\compat\v1\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import config
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\config\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import experimental
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v1\config\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.config import disable_mlir_graph_optimization
ImportError: cannot import name 'disable_mlir_graph_optimization' from 'tensorflow.python.framework.config' (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\config.py)
```

Comment: Can you please check this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370953/error-while-import-tensorflow-module

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that page but still can't resolve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to append the location of the module that might solve your error I have had the same error... You can do the following steps

Step - 1: `pip show <module-name>`
When you run this in command terminal, It will produce the location of the module.

Step - 2: Add the following code to your project

```
import sys
sys.path.append("<file location>")
```

This is how I solved my error with the following code

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/users/family/anacondanew/lib/site-packages")
```